# Retrieving like counts on entries from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, social-media-like

I've been adding a like feature to an entries database... here's the structure of the DBs:

```
**Users**
user_id
user_name
etc.

**Entries**
entry_id
entry_content
etc.

**Likes**
user_id
entry_id
```

(It's a little more complicated than that, there are groups/categories, but that should explain it fine...) Here's the SQL query I'm working with at the moment:

```
SELECT 
entries.*,
DATE_FORMAT(entry_date, "%M %D, %Y") as entry_date,
groups.group_short_name,
users.user_name, users.user_id,
FROM entries 
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.group_id = entries.group_id 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = entries.user_id 
ORDER BY entry_date DESC
```

I'm trying to also retrieve likes per entry with this query and wondering if it is possible. I've been trying:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT likes.like_id) as likes
```

with

```
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.entry_id = entries.entry_id
```

But I don't think that is anywhere near right. Am I way off? Is this possible? Hope it all made sense.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your tables aliases, for one..

```
FROM entries e
```

Then add a column query:

```
select e.*, (select count(*) from Likes where entry_id = e.entry_id) as entry_likes
```

Comment: Oops hit enter too fast... just wondering, why should I need to give my tables aliases? Is it so bad to write 'entries' instead of 'e' each time? I'm only doing it a couple times...

Comment: @Ian I always do it for a number of reasons.. It makes writing queries easier, you're more informed and precise when creating self joins and sub-queries, and I haven't found a good reason not to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
GROUP BY entries.entry_id
```

See if that works.